# Heap allocation error while trying to store data in struct

Tags: c++, opengl

**Problem**

I would like store the position, normal and color of several cubes into a structure and store the indices of which they should be drawn, in a vector. However my approach triggers an error in **malloc.c**

**What I'm doing**

I load the locations of the cubes, along with the cube's color from a file:

```
vector<vec3> cp; // size 51
vector<vec3> cc; // size 51
readLevelFile("levelfile.txt", cp, cc);
```

I load the cube's data with an object loader:

```
vector<vec3> vertexPositions; // size 24
vector<int> indices; // size 36
vector<int> outIndices; // empty
vector<vec3> normals; // size 24
vector<vec2> uvs; // unused
loadObject("cube_with_normals.obj", vertexPositions, indices, normals, uvs, 10.0f);
```

I then create a new structure and create an instance of that:

```
struct Vertex {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 color;
    vec2 texture;
};
Vertex *cubeData = new Vertex;
```

Then iterating over the number of cube positions:

```
for (int j = 0; j < cp.size()*vertexPositions.size(); j+=vertexPositions.size()) {

    for (int i = 0; i < vertexPositions.size(); i++)
    {
        cubeData[j+i].position = vertexPositions[i]+cc[j/vertexPositions.size()];
        cubeData[j+i].normal = normals[i];
        cubeData[j+i].color = cc[j/vertexPositions.size()];

    }

    for (int i=0; i < indices.size();i++)
    {
        outIndices.push_back(indices[i]+indices.size()*(j/vertexPositions.size()));
    }

}
```

However this **triggers a breakpoint in malloc.c**

**Edit:**
Ultimately i would like the data to look like this:

```
Vertex groundData[] = {
    { vec3(-1000.0,ypos,1000.0),    vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), color, vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { vec3(-1000.0,ypos,-1000.0),   vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), color, vec2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { vec3(1000.0,ypos,-1000.0),    vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), color, vec2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
    { vec3(1000.0,ypos,1000.0),     vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), color, vec2(1.0f, 0.0f) }
};
```

This simplifies the process of storing the data in a buffer

Comment: Thats exactly how the content of a vector looks like. As I said in my comment/answer, just call `std::vector::data()` member function to retrieve the underlying array.

Comment: @Manu343726: `std::vector` does not have a `data (...)` member function unless you assume this is a question about C++11. I would suggest using `&vector [0]` instead, it is more portable.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my question: Care to explain so that I won't make the same mistake again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vertex *cubeData = new Vertex;
```

That allocates one `Vertex` only. If you wan't to allocate an array, you have to use the `new[]` operator:

```
Vertex *cubeData = new Vertex[cp.size()*vertexPositions.size()*vertexPositions.size()];
```

But why do you allocate dynamically that data if you know how to use `std::vector`, which manages automatically its size and memory?

```
std::vector<Vertex> cubeData;

for (int j = 0; j < cp.size()*vertexPositions.size(); j+=vertexPositions.size()) {

    for (int i = 0; i < vertexPositions.size(); i++)
    {
        cubeData.emplace_back();

        cubeData[j+i] vertexPositions[i]+cc[j/vertexPositions.size()];
        cubeData[j+i].normal = normals[i];
        cubeData[j+i].color = cc[j/vertexPositions.size()];

    }

    for (int i=0; i < indices.size();i++)
    {
        outIndices.push_back(indices[i]+indices.size()*(j/vertexPositions.size()));
    }
}
```

If your functions expect an array instead of a vector, there is no problem, `std::vector` has a member function `data()` which returns a pointer to the underlying array:

```
void f(Vertex* array_of_vertex);

int main()
{
    std::vector<Vertex> cubeData;

    //....

    f( cubeData.data() ); //Tah dah!
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it like this, because i later call a function that loads the data into a vertex buffer. Therefore I would like the structure to be like the vertex struct.

Comment: @Attaque If you need the underlying array of the vector later, just call its [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member.

Comment: Ah, I see! I think it might be working now, however my positioning of the cubes is wrong. I'm gonna try and fix that

Comment: Finally worked out the wrong transformation, so that I could confirm your answer solved my problem. Thank you Manu343726

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you only allocate *one* `Vertex` object for `cubeData`. You have a massive memory overwrite in your loops.